# GLFW will not compile

Tags: c++, glfw

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdsfpEq.o: warning: relocation against `glad_glViewport' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdsfpEq.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `gladLoadGLLoader'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdsfpEq.o: in function `framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `glad_glViewport'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand this error when I tried to compile GFLW. I compiled by doing `` g++ main.cpp -o gl `pkg-config --libs --cflags glfw3 ``  because I'm on Arch Linux. I generated the GLAD headers, put it in my folder, and then compiled it. I used the example code so I dont know what's wrong.

Note that this does not error when I do

```
int main()
{
   glfwInit();
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
   //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
   return 0;
}
```

this works. I include by

```
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
```

and the code where I ran was https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/1.1.hello_window/hello_window.cpp

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mainly based on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186517/which-package-to-install-to-get-header-file-glad-h?newreg=8e2391c238794ae7b156555626b6e0fc).  You need to compile `glad.c` before you compile the code that you are writing.  First, make sure that you have `libglfw3-dev` installed.  Then compile `glad.c` with this line:

```
g++ -c glad.c
```

Then compile the code like this:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test glad.o -lglfw -ldl
```